# Java polymorphism - getting child command from parent map

Tags: java, polymorphism, parent-child

I've made two classes - `Building` and `Warehouse`. `Warehouse` extends `Building`. I've created `Building` map (`building_map`), where I've put both `Building` objects and `Warehouse` objects. 
I'd like to get `Warehouse`'s method by using the map, but I can see only things that are from `Building` class.

```
building_map.get(ware_id);   /*--Warehouse_function--*/;
```

(It's one of my first posts here so sorry if I've put too little informations on my problem)

EDIT:
Here's how I'm adding objects into the map:

```
        public static Map<String, Building> building_map = new HashMap<>();

Building bD_02 = new Building("bD_02", 2, "Duargian", 2.5, 180, 450, 100, ""
                + "i0_024!i0_029!i0_036?90!10!10!" //upgrade lv 1
                + "&" 
                + "" //upgrade lv 2
                + "&" 
                + "" //upgrade lv 3
                + "&");

Building bD_03 = new Warehouse("bD_03", 3, "Duargian", 2.8, 800, 2500, 1500, 2.35, 3000, ""
                + "i0_021!i0_024!i0_029?200!500!70!" //upgrade lv 1
                + "&" 
                + "" //upgrade lv 2
                + "&" 
                + "" //upgrade lv 3
                + "&");

    building_map.put("bD_02", bD_02);                      
    building_map.put("bD_03", bD_03);
```

EDIT2:
Thanks, TungstenX! It worked, I can close the topic now.

Comment: Please read about java naming conventions: no _ char in names (unless constants). This isnt python ;-) And please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. That example you give here is simply insufficient, it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Please add code of how your building_map

Comment: I've updated the question with code of building_map.

Comment: you will have to check the object's type with `instanceof` and cast it to `Warehouse`

Comment: See also the official tutorial to get started: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the result of the get to a warehouse assuming that you extended Warehouse with Building. I.e `class Warehouse extends Building`

And your map looks like:
`Map<String, Building> buildingMap = new HashMap<>();`
Then you can do

**Update: Safe casting**

```
Building building = buildingMap.get("A");
if (building instanceof Warehouse) {
    ((Warehouse)building).warehousMethod();
}
```

Comment: what if the value of `building_map.get("key")` is a Building object?

Comment: Oh, it worked! Thank you for help, that's the thing I was looking for!

Comment: @JackFlamp You are correct, I just gave an example ;-) Always check you objects

Comment: @FumyaHero Welcome to SO. Please select the solution/answer that suited you best.

Comment: Could you add safe casting to this post? Would be the cleanest.

Answer (score 2):

If you a have a map of `Building`s, not every object there has to be a `Warehouse`. It can also be a `Building` or other implementation.

If you're **sure** it's a warehouse, then you can cast it, like so:

```
Map<String, Building> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("b", new Building());
map.put("w", new Warehouse());

Warehouse w = (Warehouse) map.get("w");
w.yourMethod();
```

but keep in mind that someone can put another instance of a child of `Bulding`, like so

```
class OtherClass extends Building {}
map.put("b", new Building());
map.put("w", new Warehouse());
map.put("o", new OtherClass());

Warehouse w = (Warehouse) map.get("b");  // ClassCastException
Warehouse w = (Warehouse) map.get("o");  // ClassCastException
```

PS: As @Przemyslaw Kruglej suggested, if you want to validate an implementation of a class in a generic collection (like map) **in runtime** you can use `instanceof` before casting:

```
Building possibleWarehouse = map.get("w");
if (possibleWarehouse instanceof Warehouse) { // true
    Warehouse warehouse = (Warehouse) possibleWarehouse;
}
```

Comment: +1, but it would be better if you provided some information about `instanceof` usage in this case to prevent the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej Yes, I could but I didn't want to enourage such coding standards. It's better to design a better architecture, than to design it bad and then `instanceof` around it :) You're right though.

Comment: Danon sure I understand, however, `instanceof` is there if needed and even if it is better to use another design, it is still good to know there is something like `instanceof` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Values in map are Building type, so return type Object is expected to be building type. If as a developer you know that a specific key is binded to warehouse, than typecast it to warehouse.  ((Warehouse) building_map.get("bD_03"))

Comment: take care of null also before typecasting.